# Lit property expression is not updated even though render function is called with the correct value

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-handling, web-component, lit

I encountered some strange problem where a Lit Web component with [Property Expression](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions) (`.checked`) does not get updated. Here is a simple reproduction at [Lit Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZz48L3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZz5cbiAgXG4gIDxzY3JpcHQ-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):

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`p { color: blue }`;

  @property()
  selected = false;

  render() {
    debugger;
    return html`<input type="checkbox" 
        .checked=${this.selected}
        @change=${this.handleChange} />`;
  }
  
  handleChange(e) {   
    this.selected = e.target.checked;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```html
  <simple-greeting></simple-greeting>
  
  <script>
    const chk = document.querySelector("simple-greeting");
    chk.addEventListener("change", () => {
      console.log(chk.selected);
      chk.selected = false;
    });
  </script>
```

Here, every time I click on the checkbox, the value is `true, false, true, false, true, false, ...` instead of `true` all the time because it is supposed to revert back to false by the code. (In case anyone asks me why I do this, in real scenario, my checkbox is reverted if certain condition is not met).

When debugging, `render()` is called correctly and the value for `selected` is `false` (which is correct). However the result DOM element still has its `checked` being true half of the time.

[image]

Above screenshot: `selected` is `false` but the rendered checkbox (`$0` is pointing to the checkbox, not the component) `$0.checked` is still `true`.

What is the issue here?

EDIT to add in case it helps figuring out the problem easier, if I update the property in a separate frame instead, the problem does not happen:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => chk.selected = false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the lit [documentation](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#live)

If you want to overwrite the DOM value with the bound value no matter what—use the `live()` directive

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';
import {live} from 'lit/directives/live.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`p { color: blue }`;

  @property()
  selected = false;

  render() {
     console.log(this.selected,'Render');
    return html`<input type="checkbox" 
        .checked=${live(this.selected)}
        @change=${this.handleChange} />`;
  }
  
  handleChange(e) {   
   
    this.selected = e.target.checked;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
  }
}
```

[Working Example](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-YDtcbiAgfVxuICBcbiAgaGFuZGxlQ2hhbmdlKGUpIHsgICBcbiAgIFxuICAgIHRoaXMuc2VsZWN0ZWQgPSBlLnRhcmdldC5jaGVja2VkO1xuICAgIHRoaXMuZGlzcGF0Y2hFdmVudChuZXcgRXZlbnQoXCJjaGFuZ2VcIikpO1xuICB9XG59XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZz48L3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZz5cbiAgXG4gIDxzY3JpcHQ-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)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. Btw the link you sent is still incorrect because `?checked` wouldn't work. I changed it to `.checked` and it works correctly :) I hope you don't mind I edit your post to put the correct code in.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out and making the correction. I'm glad the issue is resolved now. Feel free to edit the post to ensure accuracy.